# How many local maximum have the following differential system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $x(t),y(t)$ positive continuous real-valued functions and $a,b\in\mathbb R_{>0}$. Consider the following differential system,

\begin{cases}
  x'(t) &= -ax(t) y(t)\\
  y'(t) &= (ax(t)-b) y(t) + f(t)
\end{cases}

with initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0,y(t_0)=y_0$ and $f(t)$ a real continuous function. My question is, how can determine the numbers of 'peaks' (i.e., the number of local maximum) that have $y(t)$?.

My approach: If we consider the cases of $f=0$, then of the second equation, we have $y'=0$ so $x(t)=b/a$, and is this the unique local maximum of the system?

And what happen, when we consider a function $f\neq0$? Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $f=0$ you also need to have $x_0>b/a$, because $x(t)$ is decreasing and might not attain the value $b/a$ for any $t$.

Comment: @Cleopatra Ohh you're right, in this case I think it never reaches that value. So, never reaches the maximum. Thanks!